# opencart multistore categories doesn't show up

Tags: opencart

I installed opencart 1.5 mutlistore there is no problem in defoult site.

in 2nd site categories and products doesn't show up. 
what is the solution?

[yeni.dizayna.org](http://yeni.dizayna.org)

Answer (score 0):

To get the categories to show up in that store, you need to assign the category to the other stores (not just default) in the DATA tab of your category editor page. Note you'll also need to assign the products you have to the other stores too (Under the LINKS tab in the product editor)